# Python unintentionally deleting keys in other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When using `del` or `.pop()` on `x_copy`, the operation is magically applied to `x` as well. i.e. keys in both dictionaries are deleted.

Example code:

```py
x = {
    "key1": 0,
    "key2": 0,
}

x_copy = x
x_copy.pop("key1")

print(f"x =      {x}")
print(f"x copy = {x_copy}")
```

This code should only remove the key from `x`, but the key is lost from both dictionaries.

Actual output:

```py
>>> x =      {'key2': 0}
>>> x copy = {'key2': 0}
```

Expected output

```
>>> x =      {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0}
>>> x copy = {'key2': 0}
```

Same happens if I replace `.pop()` with `del`:

```py
x_copy = x
x_copy.pop("key1")
```

---

Why is this happening?

*Python 3.10*

Comment: Because you didn't copy the dictionary, you have just given another name to it.
https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-copy-a-dictionary-in-python-/

Comment: because you set `x_copy = x`, in memory both variables have the same value because you assign them to the same memory

Comment: Thank you, you can post that as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_copy = x` gives you 2 variables pointing at the same place in memory and all the operations that modify one will be reflected in another. You need to actually create another object in memory (e.g. with `x.copy()`)and then you can treat it as an indepentant copy.
https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-copy-a-dictionary-in-python-/

Answer (score 0):

Didn't make shallow copy

```
x.copy()
```

Answered by @matszwecja